How do I append to an array in another ViewController?
I have a ViewController (planExercise) which stores an array of Exercise Objects:
class planExercise: UIViewController {
    var exerciseList = [
        Exercise(type: "Cardiovascular", name: "Walking", imageName: "walking", calories: 150, time: 30, isComplete: false),
        Exercise(type:"Strength",name:"Chair Squats",imageName:"cycling", calories: 200, time: 15, isComplete: false),
        Exercise(type: "Flexibility", name: "Seated Toe Touch", imageName: "squats", calories: 100, time: 15, isComplete: false)
    ]

I have another ViewController (TableViewDetail) which basically adds to the exerciseList array when I click a button, this is what I have so far:
@IBAction func didTapAdd(){
    planExercise().exerciseList.append(selectedExercise)
}

I tried to call the planExercise ViewController in the TableViewDetail ViewController and then access the exerciseList array in it and append the selectedExercise into it, however when I run the application, nothing happens to the exerciseList array in the planExercise ViewController and it does not get updated.

planExercise() is short for planExercise.init(), now with the init, it's more explicit, it create a new instance, so you aren't appending to the existing instance you think of, you do it on a new one. Keep a reference to the one you want. Now unreleased, but start your classes with an uppercase: planExercise -> PlanExercise()

Because planExercise()  here
planExercise().exerciseList.append(selectedExercise)

is a new instance other than the shown one , you need to use a delegate to pass the actual one which you want to alter it's array
 class TableViewDetail: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate:YourDelegate?
    .....
    @IBAction func didTapAdd(){
       delegate?.exerciseList.append(selectedExercise) 
    }
  }
 

Now when you show TableViewDetail from inside planExercise
let des = TableViewDetail()
des.delegate = self
present(des.....

